# Disable ASP Button if Variable is null

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I'm sure this is simple, I need to disable a button on my html page if a variable doesn't have a value from inside the code.

```
        <asp:Linkbutton ID="eastMinute" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Open Once" Width="95%" />
```

I've found several options for disabling the button if there is no text for form validation but I haven't found a way to actually connect the VB code with my ASPX page...

My thought was:

```
    'Logic for button enable
    If (username.Length < 0) Then eastOpen_Click.Enabled = False
    Else eastOpen_Click.Enabled = True
```

But with that I get an argument not specified error.

Comment: Is that a typo in your code, or is that your problem?  You've got a stray `(` after your else.

Comment: Typo, problem persists!

Comment: And can you add the full error to your question?

Comment: Based on your comment on the answer by CodingGorilla it seems the problem was a simple typographical error (`eastOpen_Click` instead of `eastMinute`). If that is the case, the question should be deleted as it is unlikely to help other users.

Comment: You may want to add some logic to the if as `username` may be null and cause an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up having to do for this to work properly was do the logic for if the value was passed or not and then add an attribute manually to my button using Attributes.Add().

```
    'Logic for button enable
    If (username Is Nothing) Then eastOpen.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled") Else
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on this from your sample:

```
<asp:Linkbutton ID="eastMinute" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Open Once" Width="95%" />
```

Your button name is `eastMinute`, so your code should be:

```
'Logic for button enable
If (username.Length < 0) Then eastMinute.Enabled = False
Else eastMinute.Enabled = True
```

The `eastOpen_Click` sounds like an event handler; that is a function and therefore does not have an `Enabled` property.

Comment: I realized what I had done right before refreshing the page. I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it in one line like:

```
eastMinute.Enabled = (username.Length < 0)
```